# ASP.NET and Active Directory - Messages Globalization

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, globalization

I have an application developed in ASP.NET and uses Active Directory for authentication. 
The error messages from Active Directory, when published on my computer, appear in Portuguese, but, when published on server, they appear in English and must appear in Portuguese. I have already put the globalization tag in the Web.config and not resolved. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide some sample errors? How are you getting them on your PC versus in your app?

Comment: It's same app published in different places. There are no mistakes, only messages appear in different languages.